# Is optical zoom same at corresponding distance?

Tags: iphone, camera

Suppose I have an [iPhone 12 Pro](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP831). This model has a 0.5x, 1x, and 2x optical zoom.

Does taking photos with the following native zooms and distances the same quality?

- 0.5x at 0.5 meter away from subject
- 1x at 1 meter away from subject
- 2x at 2 meter away from subject

Comment: This is primarily a photography or optics question which probably has come up before on related sites. It also depends on what you mean with "quality". The short answer most likely is "No".

Comment: The most obvious differences will be in perspective & depth of field - but these are artistic choices, not 'quality' differences.

Answer (score 1):

No - lenses are not perfect and each makes compromises based on size / weight / elements. iPhone cameras are constrained by space much more than traditional DSLR lenses so the difference isn't a huge as a $45 basic lens and a $4500 pro lens, but you can do the experiment yourself and measure the pixels / focus / exposure in low light to see why your three situations are not the same quality in general.

Only for highly specific conditions like absolutely still camera and subject, tons of bright light and good focusing pixel contrast subject would these all be mostly equivalent.